# Deploy failed for fastidious-tiramisu-e73d9d backend Nodejs

Tags: node.js, dependencies, netlify

```
10:45:09 AM: build-image version: 91488c6c0412f5c1c00fb34eff5c1fc41a32bce9 (focal)
10:45:09 AM: buildbot version: 91488c6c0412f5c1c00fb34eff5c1fc41a32bce9
10:45:09 AM: Building without cache
10:45:09 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:45:09 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:45:09 AM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/huynhdev24/shop-api
10:45:09 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/features
10:45:11 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
10:45:12 AM: Starting to install dependencies
10:45:12 AM: Python version set to 3.8
10:45:13 AM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
10:45:13 AM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
10:45:14 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
10:45:14 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
10:45:14 AM: Installing Go version 1.19.5 (requested 1.19.5)
10:45:19 AM: go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64
10:45:19 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
10:45:20 AM: v16.20.0 is already installed.
10:45:21 AM: Now using node v16.20.0 (npm v8.19.4)
10:45:21 AM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
10:45:21 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:45:21 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:45:21 AM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
10:45:21 AM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
10:45:21 AM: No npm workspaces detected
10:45:21 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:45:21 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:45:21 AM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.4
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: mongoose-slugger-plugin@3.1.0
10:45:22 AM: Failed during stage 'Install dependencies': dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! Found: mongoose@7.0.3
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!   mongoose@"^7.0.3" from the root project
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^5.0.0" from mongoose-slugger-plugin@3.1.0
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose-slugger-plugin
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!   mongoose-slugger-plugin@"^3.1.0" from the root project
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: mongoose@5.13.17
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!   peer mongoose@"^5.0.0" from mongoose-slugger-plugin@3.1.0
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/mongoose-slugger-plugin
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!     mongoose-slugger-plugin@"^3.1.0" from the root project
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:45:22 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-04-16T03_45_21_809Z-debug-0.log
10:45:22 AM: Error during npm install
10:45:22 AM: Build was terminated: dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:45:22 AM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
10:45:22 AM: Finished processing build request in 13.441s
```

I'm having trouble installing dependencies

I want to install the dependencies to deploy the api

Comment: now mongoose-slugger-plugin is no longer updated so i changed to slugify and it worked!